# Error: Getting error while accessing csv file contains boolean value

Tags: python-3.x, csv, boto3

I have to upload items from CSV to dynamodb table item. My CSV file contains bool datatype 
so getting raise ParamValidationError (`Invalid type <str> ,valid type <bool>`).

How to change the str type to boolean in CSV in python? How to access that?

```
"ATTRIBUTE (S)","DESCRIPTION (S)","IS_OVERRIDABLE (BOOL)"
"AAA",           "BBB",             "true"
```

Comment: if your items are like "true" and "false", you can use ```eval``` to make them booleans.

posting a sample of your csv might help to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from distutils import util
bool(util.strtobool('False')) # return False
bool(util.strtobool('True')) # return True
```

util.strtobool(str) #returns 0 for 'False', 1 for 'True'